# Como obter as médias dos tamanhos de um agrupamento com Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Dado um [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/index.html) [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), com os dados numa estrutura desse tipo:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
    'tipo': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd'],
    'ano': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001],
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(raw_data)
```

Quero obter as médias dos números de itens de diferentes tipos por ano.

Agrupando com: `df.groupby(['tipo', 'ano']).size()` obtenho os números de itens por tipo em cada ano em uma [Pandas Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.html):

```
tipo  ano 
a     2000    2
b     2000    1
c     2001    3
d     2001    1
dtype: int64
```

Quero obter as médias desses números por ano, como em:

```
ano     media
2000    1.5
2001    2.0
```

com o fim de plotá-las, usando Pandas.

Tentei fazer isso com Pandas, mas depois de um tempo tentando usar a API e falhando acabei desistindo e fiz com Python mesmo, usando um dicionário e calculando as médias "na mão".

Tem um jeito simples de fazer isso usando as abstrações e API do próprio Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme [resposta que acabei de obter no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390144/149872), a solução é fazer outro groupby especificando o parãmetro `level`:

```
df.groupby(['tipo', 'ano']).size().groupby(level=1).mean()

ano
2000    1.5
2001    2.0
dtype: float64
```